# Eclipse: Android XML Layout editor text editor is missing

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, adt

I recently switched to Arch Linux for my daily driver OS and had to reinstall my android sdk and eclipse. 
Now I wanted to edit a layout xml file for android, but the XML editor is missing, I only can use the useless graphical editor.

I use eclipse juno. I used it before, on Linux Mint, and there was everyhting fine.

**Here is a screenshot how it look in my eclipse:**
[image: Eclipse Missing Part]

**Here is a screenshot how it should look like:** 
[image: Eclipse Good]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dark Juno Theme was hiding those buttons.

Comment: Even with that theme not showing the remaining tabs, you can switch between them using Alt-F7.